# Как отловить переход по якорю, если он не изменился и hashchange не сработал?

Tags: javascript, html

Ситуация такова:

1. Переходим на какую-нибудь ссылку с #якорем
2. Якорь изменился, hashchange сработал как положено, браузер докрутил до элемента с данным id
3. Прокручиваем страницу куда-нибудь
4. Ставим фокус на адресную строку (в которой написан #якорь из пункта 1) и просто тыкаем Enter
5. Очевидно, якорь не изменился, и hashchange не сработал
6. Но браузер всё равно докрутил до элемента с данным id!

Проблема в том, что на сайте фиксированная шапка вверху страницы, и, когда браузер прокручивает страницу к элементу по #якорю — этот элемент прячется под шапкой. Мне нужно отловить событие и прокрутить страницу вверх на сотню пикселей, чтоб элемент вылез из-под шапки, но якорь не всегда меняется.

Если hashchange не всегда срабатывает, можно ли как-то ещё отловить событие прокрутки страницы к якорю?

---

Кстати, проблему очень легко воспроизвести прямо на Stack Overflow:

1. Допишите к адресу `#mainbar` — страница докрутится к началу текста вопроса.
2. Ткните Enter в адресной строке, не изменяя адрес (`#mainbar` должен остаться) — текст вопроса уедет под шапку!

Видео с демонстрацией (см. комментарии в консоли): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7bTqC97gRnA

---

UPD: обнаружил, что в современных браузерах появилось CSS-свойство [scroll-padding-top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-padding-top), которое позволяет решить продемонстрированную выше проблему с шапкой и прокруткой.

Тем не менее, поскольку вопрос изначально не про прокрутку, а про отлов события hashchange — он всё ещё актуален.

Comment: Не вариант ли отслеживать положение прокрутки на странице? Делали сайт, где нужно было отслеживать положение шапки и либо выводить её краткий вариант, либо развернутый. Чтобы избежать промежуточных вариантов — смотрели за положением скролла страницы по вертикали. Соответственно, вы также можете немного поднимать страницу, если браузер простоял 150мс в зоне, скрывающей нужный вам контент.

Comment: @sirWill а как надёжно отличить переход по якорю от просто прокрутки? Ведь если пользователь сам покрутил колёсико мыши, то не нужно за него решать (а при переходе по якорю страница в отдельных случаях может прокрутиться всего на несколько пикселей, что весьма похоже на прокрутку колёсиком)

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за комментарий) Он навел меня на решение:
Чтобы корректировать прокрутку на странице нужно отслеживать несколько условий для всевозможных сценариев они будут следующие:

1 вариант — отслеживать не изменения в строке URL, а клик по ссылкам с якорем. При таком подходе открутка произойдет даже в случае, если уже был клик по этому якорю и он есть в URL страницы.

```
$('[href="#anchorname"]").on('click', ...);
```

2 вариант — нажатие Enter в адресной строке приводит к перезагрузке страницы. И тут всё просто — смотрим событие загрузки страницы, проверяем есть ли в адресе якорь и откручиваем в нужное место для этого якоря.

Comment: Нет, при нажатии Enter в адресной строке с якорем страница не перезагружается (иначе проблемы бы не было)

Comment: Это в каком браузере по нажатию Enter в строке браузера не происходит перезагрузки? В Chrome/Safari пробую — перегружает полностью страницу, при этом неважно добавлен якорь или нет.

Comment: На случай загрузки страницы по нажатию Enter в строке браузера из кеша, что, возможно, происходит без полной перезагрузки страницы (хотя на мой взгляд это оч странное поведение, которое я не замечал) можно отлавливать событие onpageshow тега body.

Comment: Просто прямо на этой странице допишите `#mainbar1`, перейдите (иногда страница на Stack Overflow перезагружается, не знаю почему), а потом сотрите 1 и снова ткните Enter — страница абсолютно точно не перезагрузится (если после этого снова ткнуть Enter, то случится проблема, которую я описал в вопросе)

Comment: Ок) Такой подход это не просто нажатие Enter в строке с URL. Это создание события hashchange, которое можно отловить в window.onhashchange и также прекрасно отработать по нему, проверив, а тот ли якорь там стоит.

Comment: Нет, никакого события hashchange нет. Раз вы до сих пор не понимаете, попробую видео записать

Comment: только что в инструментах разработчика нативным js добавил `window.onhashchange = function(e){console.log('CHANGE! ', e)}` и проделал то, что вы описываете. Оно генерируется.

Comment: Сейчас проделаю то же самое и на видео покажу, что ничего не генерируется :)

Comment: Воть https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7bTqC97gRnA

Comment: Ох уж этот Firefox) Странное они поведение выбрали: откручивать страницу при enter в адресе страницы, взамен обновления страницы, как это делают Webkit браузеры. Что ж... тогда возможно подойдет вариант отдельной проверки, что это Firefox ;), затем ловить onscroll события и убеждаться, что не было до этого сгенерировано событие onwheel (а также нажатия стрелок клавиатуры), то есть это не пользователь крутит страницу.

Comment: Не надо наезжать на Firefox, всё то же самое в IE, Edge и умершей Opera 12, это вебкиты выпендриваются :)

Comment: @andreymal Наезжать надо. Потому что если я нажимаю на enter в адресной строке, я ожидаю, что страница будет перезагружена. А то развели ромашку - якорь есть - не перегружаем, якоря нет - перегружаем.

Answer (score 1):

Не надо ничего обрабатывать. И вообще не надо пихать скрипты туда, где вполне достаточно стилей. Надо просто элементам с id прописать правильно отступы (значение 32px - это высота фиксированной шапки):

```
section { padding-top: 32px; margin-bottom: -32px; }
section:last-child { margin-bottom: 0; }
```

А вот пример полностью:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
html, body, main { height: 100%; margin: 0; }
main { overflow: auto; }
nav { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 16px; line-height: 32px; background: white; text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid; }
a { display: inline-block; padding: 0 .5em; }
a:hover { background: silver; }
section { padding-top: 32px; margin-bottom: -32px; }
section:last-child { margin-bottom: 0; }
h1 { margin: 16px 0; background: antiquewhite; }
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#s1">1</a>
  <a href="#s2">2</a>
  <a href="#s3">3</a>
  <a href="#s4">4</a>
  <a href="#s5">5</a>
  <a href="#s6">6</a>
  <a href="#s7">7</a>
  <a href="#s8">8</a>
  <a href="#s9">9</a>
  <a href="#s10">10</a>
</nav>

<main>
  <section id=s1>
    <h1>1</h1>
    <p>Проблема в том, что на сайте фиксированная шапка вверху страницы, и, когда браузер прокручивает страницу к элементу по #якорю — этот элемент прячется под шапкой. Мне нужно отловить событие и прокрутить страницу вверх на сотню пикселей, чтоб элемент вылез из-под шапки, но якорь не всегда меняется.</p>
  </section>
  <section id=s2>
    <h1>2</h1>
    <p>Проблема в том, что на сайте фиксированная шапка вверху страницы, и, когда браузер прокручивает страницу к элементу по #якорю — этот элемент прячется под шапкой. Мне нужно отловить событие и прокрутить страницу вверх на сотню пикселей, чтоб элемент вылез из-под шапки, но якорь не всегда меняется.</p>
  </section>
  <section id=s3>
    <h1>3</h1>
    <p>Проблема в том, что на сайте фиксированная шапка вверху страницы, и, когда браузер прокручивает страницу к элементу по #якорю — этот элемент прячется под шапкой. Мне нужно отловить событие и прокрутить страницу вверх на сотню пикселей, чтоб элемент вылез из-под шапки, но якорь не всегда меняется.</p>
  </section>
  <section id=s4>
    <h1>4</h1>
    <p>Проблема в том, что на сайте фиксированная шапка вверху страницы, и, когда браузер прокручивает страницу к элементу по #якорю — этот элемент прячется под шапкой. Мне нужно отловить событие и прокрутить страницу вверх на сотню пикселей, чтоб элемент вылез из-под шапки, но якорь не всегда меняется.</p>
  </section>
  <section id=s5>
    <h1>5</h1>
    <p>Проблема в том, что на сайте фиксированная шапка вверху страницы, и, когда браузер прокручивает страницу к элементу по #якорю — этот элемент прячется под шапкой. Мне нужно отловить событие и прокрутить страницу вверх на сотню пикселей, чтоб элемент вылез из-под шапки, но якорь не всегда меняется.</p>
  </section>
  <section id=s6>
    <h1>6</h1>
    <p>Проблема в том, что на сайте фиксированная шапка вверху страницы, и, когда браузер прокручивает страницу к элементу по #якорю — этот элемент прячется под шапкой. Мне нужно отловить событие и прокрутить страницу вверх на сотню пикселей, чтоб элемент вылез из-под шапки, но якорь не всегда меняется.</p>
  </section>
  <section id=s7>
    <h1>7</h1>
    <p>Проблема в том, что на сайте фиксированная шапка вверху страницы, и, когда браузер прокручивает страницу к элементу по #якорю — этот элемент прячется под шапкой. Мне нужно отловить событие и прокрутить страницу вверх на сотню пикселей, чтоб элемент вылез из-под шапки, но якорь не всегда меняется.</p>
  </section>
  <section id=s8>
    <h1>8</h1>
    <p>Проблема в том, что на сайте фиксированная шапка вверху страницы, и, когда браузер прокручивает страницу к элементу по #якорю — этот элемент прячется под шапкой. Мне нужно отловить событие и прокрутить страницу вверх на сотню пикселей, чтоб элемент вылез из-под шапки, но якорь не всегда меняется.</p>
  </section>
  <section id=s9>
    <h1>9</h1>
    <p>Проблема в том, что на сайте фиксированная шапка вверху страницы, и, когда браузер прокручивает страницу к элементу по #якорю — этот элемент прячется под шапкой. Мне нужно отловить событие и прокрутить страницу вверх на сотню пикселей, чтоб элемент вылез из-под шапки, но якорь не всегда меняется.</p>
  </section>
  <section id=s10>
    <h1>10</h1>
    <p>Проблема в том, что на сайте фиксированная шапка вверху страницы, и, когда браузер прокручивает страницу к элементу по #якорю — этот элемент прячется под шапкой. Мне нужно отловить событие и прокрутить страницу вверх на сотню пикселей, чтоб элемент вылез из-под шапки, но якорь не всегда меняется.</p>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Отрицательный маргин — яркий признак костыля. К тому же в моём случае высота шапки вообще динамическая :)

Comment: @andreymal, не всегда. А вот шапка с динамической высотой - это странно. А что если контейнер подвинуть?

Comment: Контейнер и так подвинут (и это пододвигание тоже обновляется джаваскриптом), но а толку, если браузер всё равно это учитывает и прокручивает якорь аккурат к верху окна браузера, игнорируя все шапки и пододвигания

Comment: (мечты-мечты: вот бы была возможность указать браузеру область видимости на странице, которая не перекрыта шапками, чтобы не только якоря, но и PageUp/PageDown корректно без костылей работали)

Comment: @andreymal, для этого вроде надо просто область скролла помеянть?

Comment: Но почему-то так никто не делает (можно даже на шапку того же Stack Overflow посмотреть), да и это вроде бы снижает юзерфрендли в некоторых нюансах

Answer (score 0):

**Вы не отследите это событие универсально**, так как к примеру в `Google Chrome` при аналогичных действиях, по нажатию <kbd>Enter</kbd> в адресной строке - страница будет полностью перезагружена.

Comment: Зато во всех остальных браузерах - не будет. Там и надо отследить.